# Inserting CHtmlEditView

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to show CHtmlEditView in my application. If I create SDI application with wizard and set view as CHtmlEditView it works. I want to create a simple dialog and embed CHtmlEditView into my dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is just two of samples that show you how to insert a CView derived view into a CDialog:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1369/Inserting-a-Doc-Frame-View-in-a-dialog-using-a-cus

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/article.php/c5007/Creating-a-View-on-a-Dialog.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have found those samples as well. I wish I could get much more practical solution. I want to achieve something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1366/Using-the-new-HTML-Editing-classes-in-MFC. But I don't know how to put a dialog inside the frame and attach htmleditview. Since I have a hard time to understand this Document/View architecture of MFC.